# wifi doesn't work with various error messages

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, loop-device

I've upgraded to ubuntu 16 , then I've a problem with wifi as it doesn't work and gives me message "device not ready" when it try to make the dev up

```
$sudo ip link set wlo1 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

the device with blocked, so I unblock it, then I received a different message

```
$sudo rfkill unblock wifi 
sudo ip link set wlo1 up
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
```

i found that there is a problem with loading module **rt2800pci** and the output of ***dmesg*** contains that error

```
    [ 1418.415901] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1420.015845] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1420.015851] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
[ 1421.635703] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1423.235726] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1423.235733] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
[ 1424.851615] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1426.451591] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1426.451597] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
[ 1437.995145] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1439.599083] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1439.599089] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
[ 1441.215039] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1442.814958] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[ 1442.814964] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
```

I was using kernel version 4.4 i tried to change it to 4.5 but the problem still unsolved

```
 uname -a
    Linux PC 4.5.0-040500-generic #201603140130 SMP Mon Mar 14 05:32:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does **sudo service network-manager restart** solved your problem, if not could you give output for **sudo lshw -class network** command

Comment: What is the laptop model?