# Unable to connect to internet through WiFi, wlp3s0: unavailable

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, iwlwifi

## The Problem

Wifi worked fine on initial install of my Xubuntu a few years ago but stopped working somewhere down the line. Here's how my nm-applet looked [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Weh9w.png)

```
$ ip link
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:a9:82:0b:3a:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I try to bring it up, I get

```
~$ sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
```

so I tried using the `nmcli` command which gave me this

```
~$ nmcli
wlp3s0: unavailable
        "Intel Centrino 1000"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 8C:A9:82:0B:3A:BA, hw, mtu 1500

~$ sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan | grep -i ssid
command failed: Network is down (-100)
```

## Attempt to fix

**I tried** looking up for `RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error` and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010309/rtnetlink-answers-input-output-error-given-when-trying-to-bring-interface-up) post. This person's problem is a bit different but I did tried reloading the drivers as suggested with

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

And I got no output/ error but the wifi still did not work and `wlp3s0` state was still `DOWN`. Next I went to [intel's website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and downloaded the drivers for `Centrino Wireless-N 1000 kernel 3.2+`. Then I put the file inside `/lib/firmware/` and rebooted but the wifi was still not working.

## System info

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Distribution - Xubuntu v4.16
- `~$ uname -r -> 5.15.0-57-generic`
- According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031439/am-i-running-networkmanager-or-networkd) post I have systemd-networkd

## Network-card related info and other output

btw please know I don't know what any of these commands actually do since I am an average user.

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network

  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 8c:a9:82:0b:3a:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-57-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:27 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
```

```
:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0042 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Usb Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6461 Microdia Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
:~$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

```
:~$ rfkill list all

1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware

[    0.117997] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.291665] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.315364] pci 0000:04:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
[   33.150445] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[   36.811949] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   36.927902] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   36.962509] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   47.071025] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   47.120886] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   57.026283] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   57.071335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   67.026148] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   67.072932] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   77.132028] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   77.168643] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   87.186535] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[   87.221060] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[  626.936926] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 1146.332238] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2060.970620] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[ 2061.182573] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2061.224861] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2071.163750] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2081.164626] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2091.165254] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2101.164889] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2111.163566] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2115.383171] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2990.003542] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[ 2990.178740] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 2990.224992] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 3000.136187] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 3010.136424] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 3020.136604] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 3030.135232] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
[ 3040.130252] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138 1000-5.ucode
```

```
:~$ sudo service systemd-networkd status

● systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023xxx; 1h 8min ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 1104 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3273)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 110ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─1104 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Jan 12 21:36:19 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: Enumeration completed
Jan 12 21:36:19 user1 systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
Jan 12 21:36:20 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: enp4s0: Link UP
Jan 12 21:36:20 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: enp4s0: Gained carrier
Jan 12 21:36:22 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: enp4s0: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 12 21:36:24 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: docker0: Link UP
Jan 12 22:10:05 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: wlan0: Interface name change detected, renamed to wlp3s>
Jan 12 22:10:05 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: wlp3s0: Failed
Jan 12 22:25:34 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: wlan0: Interface name change detected, renamed to wlp3s>
Jan 12 22:25:34 user1 systemd-networkd[1104]: wlp3s0: Failed
```

As asked by @Jeremy32, Here's the output for `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

https://pastebin.com/iK9TuVKu

As asked by @chili555, Here's the for `cat /etc/network/interface` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*


:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: I suspect the dmesg | grep firmware missed some errors, please edit to add results for `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

Comment: May we also see: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` as well as: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jeremy31 sorry for the late reply. https://pastebin.com/iK9TuVKu

Comment: @chili555 I've added the output at the end of the post. Also, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: This is Ubuntu Server correct? If it is, the NetworkManager renderer doesn't work for anything and this is just ultimately going to cause tons of problems. Netplan OR NetworkManager, don't try to hybrid it it's very unstable. On paper that configuration should work , but in reality it doesn't.

NetworkManager here doesn't have a configuration at all it look like to me, so it has no connection configured. You can verify that with `nmcli connection show`, and there should be an entry there with your WIFI SSID.  Just turning on the link won't do it.

Your kernel is def seeing the wifi device.

Comment: @sean it's not a server it's all in a desktop environment, namely xubuntu. This is what `nmcli` shows https://i.imgur.com/MV4mavD.png
I think I might have, while trying to fix my problem, installed things that conflict with each other. Things like netplan and network manager.

Comment: Netplan and Network Manager do not conflict assuming that the netplan yaml file is properly configured as yours appears to be. Is this a dual boot with Windows? Does the wireless work in Windows? Is Fast Boot turned off in Windows? What is the result of: ls -al /lib/firmware/iwllwifi-1000-5.ucode? We hope it is size 337520.

Comment: @sean do I unmask the netplan thing now or do I just keep it masked?

Comment: sean correctly deleted his answer. Please do not follow those steps.

Comment: @chili555 Yes the network worked on windows but that was eons ago. no this is not a dual boot. It also worked on this very install of Ubuntu in the beginning and because I used wifi initially and then got a ethernet connection later on and forgot about the wifi. I'll check the fast boot thing in my bios. And there's no `iwllwifi-1000-5.ucode` so I am guessing you mean `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode`? case that is in fact 337520.

Comment: @chili555 I already followed everything by the time sean deleted the answer. I'll try to reverse any steps that I can remember.

Comment: I apologize for my typo. I am suspicious about this from your paste: "Unable to initialize device." I wonder if the device itself is defective. Can you try a live session of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and see if the wireless works? If it does not work there and the `sudo dmesg | grep  iwl` shows the same ugly errors, then I suspect the device is defective.

Comment: @chili555 sorry for the delay I was trying to fix the mess that I've created. Ethernet has also stopped working so i am messaging from another device. anyhow,  that's a brilliant idea. I'll try to arrange a USB drive from someone since I don't own one and later I'll update you. thanks!

Comment: Did the wifi work during install?

Comment: @jeremy31 on my current install? yes it was working previously. In a live ubuntu environment like chilli suggested in the last comment? I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @chili555 I tried with live drive with ubuntu and my wifi and bluetooth were both not working even though on my actual OS, only wifi is not working and bluetooth is. So yea there's that. Although I'd like to point out that there have been instance where some piece of hardware doesn't work on live install but works fine after actually installing it. IIRC bluetooth and wifi both didn't work on live lubuntu but worked fine after installing it.

With that said, what do you say? Is this a lost cause?

Comment: @Jeremy31 You reckon I should try uninstalling everything network related and try installing it again from scratch? Like just purge all networkd and network manager or whatever?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, you could try booting an older kernel or reinstall linux-firmware

Comment: "uninstalling everything network related and try installing it again from scratch? Like just purge all networkd and network manager" No. As your pastebin clearly shows, it is a device/driver/firmware issue, not the networking suite. When you try a live session, what is the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Are there any new clues?

Comment: @chili555 nope. https://pastebin.com/QtYiEJzW

Comment: I am still suspicious that the hardware is at fault. Sorry.